# Dual Boot Catalina and Pop!-OS with Data-Sharing Partition

Tags: macos, partition, unix, dual-boot

I want to dual boot both an up-to-date version of macOS and an up-to-date version of Pop!-OS on my MacBook Pro 2016 without T2 chip. I am currently running macOS Catalina. Can somebody comment on the following plan I have?

1. Create two new partitions, one for Pop!-OS and one for shared data
2. Move OS-agnostic stuff from my current macOS home directory to the data partition (Including media etc. but also rc-files and configuration files)
3. Install Pop!-OS on the other partition
4. Symlink files from the data partition to both OS'

Would this be feasible in theory? Also I wondered about some details:

- Which format should I use for the data partition? HFS+?
- How do I replace the system-generated hard-copy configuration files (e.g. .bashrc) with the sym-linked ones? I.e. in which order should I delete/rename the files to avoid trouble?
- Will macOS Big Sur introduce breaking changes to this set-up?

Thank you!

Comment: PopOS Linux is so lightweight and efficient you can run it in a virtual machine. Oracles VirtualBox is free for personal while Parallels and VMware Fusion are faster and offer a blended desktop experience. Dual boot may not be worth the hassle.

Comment: @JamesBrickley Thank you for your input! This is all about running CUDA on an Nvidia GPU, so I need to run it natively. Right?

Comment: Yes likely. Have to tested PopOS on that Mac? You are likely to run into things not working so great on Linux. Most should work but there have been issues with trackpad / keyboard, power management.

Comment: @JamesBrickley Yes, I tried the live mode, and everything is working right out of the box, actually. Do you have some thoughts on my original question?

Comment: Shared storage would have to be FAT32 and you cannot symbolic link from FAT32 to another file system.  But you can mount the FAT32 system anywhere you want on Linux and symbolic link within Linux.  On macOS the FAT32 volume will be mounted in /Volumes and you can create symbolic links in macOS to point to it.  You might need to backup macOS, nuke the drive and install partitions for PopOS/Linux. Then install rEFInd utility to allow Linux / macOS dual booting.  Then install macOS and restore from backup. Might need to disable SIP with "csrutil disable" as well.

Comment: @JamesBrickley Thanks, that was a lot already! Why can I not use HFS+ for the shared data partition?

Comment: Linux has issues read/writing to JHFS+ which is Journaled HFS+ and certainly will have issues with APFS file systems.  You might be able to create a non-journaled HFS+ file system with command line diskutil. On PopOS 'sudo apt-get install hfsprogs' - sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdx# /media/mntpoint - But I wouldn't rely on it, there could be problems.  FAT32 is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @JamesBrickley Thanks again. I am having doubts about the 4GB limitation, and somehow this is revealing itself as being more complicated than I thought. Isn't there any easy way to work on the same set of files from two operating systems?

Comment: Get a NAS box. Network share data.